# How to find Max and min dependent on other element?

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I want to find the only records having Maximum salary of each different employee in the following XML by XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

`<Root>`

```
<Record recordNumber="1">
    <SALARY>20000</SALARY>
    <EMPLOYEE>Emp1</EMPLOYEE>
    <AGE>32</AGE>
</Record>
<Record recordNumber="2">
    <SALARY>34000</SALARY>
    <EMPLOYEE>Emp2</EMPLOYEE>
    <AGE>34</AGE>
</Record>
<Record recordNumber="3">
    <SALARY>12000</SALARY>
    <EMPLOYEE>Emp1</EMPLOYEE>
    <AGE>32</AGE>
</Record>
<Record recordNumber="4">
    <SALARY>15000</SALARY>
    <EMPLOYEE>Emp2</EMPLOYEE>
    <AGE>34</AGE>
</Record>
<Record recordNumber="5">
    <SALARY>22000</SALARY>
    <EMPLOYEE>Emp1</EMPLOYEE>
    <AGE>32</AGE>
</Record>
<Record recordNumber="6">
    <SALARY>35000</SALARY>
    <EMPLOYEE>Emp2</EMPLOYEE>
    <AGE>34</AGE>
</Record>
</Root>
```

Thanks in advance.

P.S.: However I pasted all XML here but preview is not same. So, Please don't mind. :)

Comment: No. I had to implement in XSLT 1.0. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With XSLT 1.0 you can use [Muechian grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.xml) to group the `Record` elements, then you can sort each group to find the Record with maximum SALARY:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="k1" match="Record" use="EMPLOYEE"/>

<xsl:template match="Root">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Record[generate-id() = generate-id(key('k1', EMPLOYEE)[1])]"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Record">
  <xsl:for-each select="key('k1', EMPLOYEE)">
    <xsl:sort select="SALARY" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
    <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
      <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: IMHO and interpretation of the question, this solution is wrong. If there are two records with equal salary and not less than any others, then they are both the maximum by definition. So in some scenarios you have to return more than one record per employee.

Comment: Sean, you are right that the code I posted outputs only one record with the maximum for each unique employee. The poster will have to clarify what is wanted, there is some wording in the question supporting your interpretation, on the other hand the sample data does not have two records for an employee with the same salary. And the question title 'How to find Max and min dependent on other element' to me more looked like a question to identify one maximum.

Comment: Thank you very much for solution. The use of key function is what I couldn't think in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

This XSLT 1.0 stylesheet will return each record which holds a maximum salary for each employee. If an employee has two or more records at maximum, all the maximum records will be returned.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="employee" match="Record" use="EMPLOYEE" />

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
 <xsl:copy>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
 </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Record[ key('employee',EMPLOYEE)/SALARY &gt; SALARY]" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If you need only one maximum record per employee returned, then please update the question and go with Martin's answer.

Comment: Sean, What should I add to the current wording of my question for only one max record(not repeated)? Thanks

Comment: How about "If there is more than one maximum, return only one of the maximum records." You could leave the choice open, or you could specify a discriminator in these cases, in terms of Age or @recordNumber.